# Join two tables and import as one Indice into Algolia?

Tags: laravel, algolia

I'm using Laravel and I'm wondering, is it possible to create a join, and then import that result as an Indice into Algolia for Searching? I know that Algolia imports models, so I'm not sure if there's a way this can be done. I'm using Laravel Scout and Algolia for search and Vue js for my front-end. This would solve the problem that I am having.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to customize the searchable data that is synchronized to Algolia by specifying `toSearchableArray()` method on the model. In that method, you can pass in the model and relation (whichever model you want to join with) data. More info: 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scout#configuring-searchable-data